# open cv close camera

Tags: python, opencv, camera

I am using OpenCv to capture image from webcam.

It works fine I just don't know how to close the camera.

```
from cv2 import *
# initialize the camera
cam = VideoCapture(0)   # 0 -> index of camera
s, img = cam.read()
if s:    # frame captured without any errors
    namedWindow("cam-test",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
    imshow("cam-test",img)`
    waitKey(0)
    destroyWindow("cam-test")
    imwrite("testfilename.jpg",img) #save image
    cam.release
```

Comment: Your code is working fine. Camera is automatically closed once you press any key because you have used waitKey(0). can you elaborate your problem?

Comment: Thank you, the camera light was blinking even after the file was written. it would only go off when the python session was closed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you're just missing `()` at the end of `cam.release`

Answer (score 0):

use below snippet

```
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0) 
 
while True:
    ret,frame=cap.read()
    
    
    cv2.imshow("window",frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF==ord("q"):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

you can change the letter "q" to any other character and by pressing the "q" letter the video will stop

Answer (score -1):

Change `CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE` to `WINDOW_AUTOSIZE`.